# Adding information from a Google Forms response to a new row in a Google Docs table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to transfer the details of a newly-submitted form response to a table I've made in a Google Docs file.

Problem: The first method I used (`.appendTable(cells)`) created a new table. My second attempt (below, which I found through searching Stack Overflow) only creates one cell and adds all the info to it. Adding the `cells` variable into `.appendTableRow()`, i.e. `.appendTableRow(cells)`, didn't work either.

The relevant snippet from my existing code:

```
// Grab the existing table.
var body = DocumentApp.openById('thedocumentid').getBody(),
searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
element = searchElement.getElement(),
table = element.asTable();

// Add the Row to the table.
var cells = [[theDate, nameWelcome, interest, value, comment, offer]];
var addRow = table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell(cells);
```

How can I add my form response information into separate cells of a new table row?

Comment: If you're using Google Form then you can always have the responses captured in a Google Spreadsheet. Each column in the spreadshset represents each question/field of google form. Google form takes care of appending the rows to existing response spreadsheet.  Sorry, I could not get the requirement to write a code... Please provide inputs here.

Comment: @aks Thank you for your feedback. The script is running inside my google spreadsheet. The function performs on form submit. I was just having trouble pushing out the results. A simple loop fixed it as answered below. I really appreciate you helping out too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? It appends a row using `insertTableCell()`.

```
var cells = [theDate, nameWelcome, interest, value, comment, offer]; // 1 dimensional array
var addRow = table.appendTableRow();
cells.forEach(function(e, i){
  addRow.insertTableCell(i, e);
});
```

#### Reference :

- [insertTableCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#inserttablecellchildindex-tablecell)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: That is a perfect fix, a loop is a great idea. Thank you

Comment: @Bjaeg I'm glad your issue was solved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.